# SQL greater than substring

Tags: sql, select

I have a single SQL field like so:

```
          ROOMS
=======================
bedrooms 2, bathrooms 2
bedrooms 3, bathrooms 2
bedrooms 6, bathrooms 1
bedrooms 1, bathrooms 4
bedrooms 1, bathrooms 2
bedrooms 4, bathrooms 4
bedrooms 1, bathrooms 3
```

How can I form a single `SELECT` statement to retrieve all rows with bedrooms greater than 3?

Also,  can this statement can be mutated to retrieve all rows with bathrooms greater than 3?

**EDIT**

Yes, yes, yes, horrible data system.  :)

Conceptually, however, is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you not divide that into two columns instead of one?  That's really the benefit to an RDBMS.

Comment: What I mean to say is ;) ~ You have a single sql field that looks like that? Or you have a table with those values, or what? You have newlines in the text? You really can't even transform that text without doing a lot of string parsing, which is _not_ the domain of SQL.

Comment: Shhh, now everyone knows I had a brain fart.

Comment: @drach - Yes, I was afraid of that.  This is a single field example from a larger table.  The query needs to work only on this data.  Or not, if it can't be done.

Comment: @moot - Let's say I can't, for now.  :)

Comment: two integer columns will also reduce storage requirements quite a bit.

Comment: Incidentally, what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Are there rooms with more than 9 bedrooms or 9 bathrooms? why you are keeping the data like this? why not using one field for bedrooms and one for bathrooms?

Comment: @Saikios - mostly because the original, larger table was not designed to have these queries performed.  FYI the equation in your personal info only adds up to 95% of "you".

Comment: @* - So you can sleep tonight, rest assured this column will be dropped from the original and remapped into a separate table.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I hope I don't have to point out what a horrible, horrible data model this is.

With that out of the way:

You'll just have to parse the data in the field. If the format is always like above, you might get away with using `substr`, as in :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE SUBSTR(BEDROOMS, 9,1)>3
```

(no guarantee for the numbers :-) ).

If the format is more flexible (e.g. more than 9 bed-/bathrooms, bathrooms given first), you'll probably need to use a regular expression to parse. Most DBMS support regular expressions, see e.g. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html

Comment: @steve Now that you clarified that you really do have data that looks like that, this would work. HOWEVER. I would really parse this in a language that is oriented around string processing, not an RDBMS system.

Comment: @drach and all - luckily, there are other options too.  Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: This approach will not work if any of the digits goes above 9. You need to cater for that.

Comment: Oh, and SQL server does not support regular expressions, unless you use a CLR function.

Comment: @Ryk: Yes, that's why I mentioned that you need to use a regex for complex cases. And it's not my fault if people use MS SQL server :-).

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is why normalization was 'invented' so that you won't end up with crappy schemas like this. WHoever designed this should be ...., anyways.

I suggest firstly to fix up the schema, and then this won't be a problem, but to answer your question, you can replace all occurences of the "bedrooms " with "" and then replace all ocurrences of the ", bathrooms " with say "-", then from there form a query.

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(ButcheredColumn, CHARINDEX('-', ButcheredColumn))) AS NumBedrooms
, CONVERT(int, RIGHT(ButcheredColumn, CHARINDEX('-', ButcheredColumn))) AS NumBathrooms
FROM (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(ROOMS, 'bedrooms ',''), ', bathrooms ', '-') AS ButcheredColumn
    FROM CrappyDesignedTable1
) AS ButhceredTable
```

might have to play with charindex a little to get the right column, then you can use this table as a subquery and select from it. And I suggest if you dont know what a subquery is, to put all your tools down and go play angry birsds on your IPhone.